# C program writing to the same file in a loop causes Windows crash

Tags: windows, crash, freeze

In the process of troubleshooting a larger program I found that the following causes my computer to reboot at a random number of iterations of the loop variable gg. I thought perhaps that opening and closing the same file was causing the problem (perhaps due to it not really being closed before the next open?), so I also tried opening a different file depending on the modulus (2) of the loop variable, but that also crashed. Does anyone know why this would crash my computer? EventViewer hasn't been very helpful, but some (not all) of the crashes are preceded by a iaStorA (Intel Application Storage Drive A). Some of the iaStorA events just cause a momentary hang, but it recovers. I have a SATA SSD.

```
int main()
{
    unsigned Cy = 17;
    unsigned Nc = 860527;

    for (int gg = 0; gg < 5000; gg++)
    {
        FILE* fid = fopen("scooby.bin", "w");
        for (unsigned cl = 0; cl < Nc; cl++)
        {
            fprintf(fid, "@Cluster%u\n", cl + 1);
        }
        fclose(fid);
        printf("gg = %d\n", gg);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Intel Rapid Storage Technology driver was the culprit. Updating to the latest driver seems to have resolved the problem.